# Get DateTime object given local time as string, date as UTC DateTime and a timezone-locale string?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm working with data from several sources, and I need to put together an accurate DateTime.

I have:

A) a `string` representing a time of day, e.g.: "4:00 pm"
B)  a `DateTime` object intended to represent a pure date, by having been created as midnight, zulu time (offset of 00:00) for a particular date.
C) a `string` representing a timezone locale, e.g.: "America/Los_Angeles"

How do I get a precise `DateTime` object, with correct number of ticks, representing the time (A) experienced in that locale (C), on that date (B)??

Comment: You should consider using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: When working with dates and times in C# I always advice to consider the usage of [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/). It avoids many of the fallacies with the built-in `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` classes.

Comment: OK, I can work with DateTimeOffset for my output, but I don't have control over those input types (A, B, C). Also, NodaTime is in bounds for any answer here, though I'll prefer a correct answer that can work without it.

Comment: There is a nice, simple TimeZone converter library here: https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter which will convert between TZDB and Windows Timezones.  Which you can then use with the .NET Timezone functions (which IIRC require at least .NET 4.5, although they may be there in 4.0 as well).

Comment: Please clarify - are you saying the date is based on the UTC day, but the time is in local time of the time zone specified?

Comment: @MattJohnson, The DateTime input (B) is a timestamp representing 12:00:00 AM +00:00 on some particular day. It could have more intuitively been just a string, like "2017-05-23" but that's what I have to work with. So, for example, if given a string of "4:00 PM" for (A), a datetime from 2017-05-23 00:00:00 +00:00 for (B) and a locale of "America/Los_Angeles" for (C) I need, as a result of these 3 inputs, a DateTime object representing the precise moment of 4pm on May 23 as experienced in Los Angeles, CA.

Comment: Oh, an the timezone input is an IANA standard timezone, not a Microsoft format.

Comment: @Faust - I got that, but is `"4:00 PM"` also based on the UTC day, or is it based on `America/Los_Angeles`?

Comment: In other words, is (A) also based on the UTC day, or is it based on the time zone (C)?  For example, if I have (A) `6:00 PM`, (B) `2015-05-23 00:00:00`, (C) `America/Los_Angeles`, is that `2015-05-23Z` + `T18:00-07:00` == `2015-05-22T18:00-07:00`? or is it `2015-05-23Z` + `T18:00Z` == `2015-05-23T18:00Z`, which is equivalent to `2015-05-23T11:00-07:00` ?   (Notice the date change with the first approach).

Comment: @MattJohnson "4:00 PM" will be based on `America/Los_Angeles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example using [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/), which is more reliable of any of the framework classes when dealing with calendars, time zones, dates and times:

```
var timeString = "4:00 pm";
var pureDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 22, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var timezoneString = "America/Los_Angeles";

var localTime = ParseTimeString(timeString);

var localDate = LocalDate.FromDateTime(pureDate);

var localDateTime = localDate.At(localTime);

var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timezoneString];

var zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(zone);
```

Inside `zonedDateTime` you will find your full date:

```
"2017-05-22T16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles (-07)"
```

You may than use `zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc()` to get a `System.DateTime` instance in UTC.

`ParseTimeString` parses your time string using your format specifier:

```
public static LocalTime ParseTimeString(string timeString)
{
    var pattern = LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("h:mm tt");
    return pattern.Parse(timeString).Value;
}
```

#### Considerations if you use `DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset` and `TimeZoneInfo`

If you do not want to use NodaTime be aware of the possible pitfalls of the built-in classes:

1. `TimeZoneInfo` in Windows uses a different specifier that is not compatible with IANA/TZDB. Your `America/Los_Angeles` time zone string will not work if you do not convert it before use (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)
2. `DateTimeOffset` (which is more reliable then `DateTime`) still loses information when created. The time zone data cannot be persisted and you will have just a date with an offset from UTC.
3. You'll need to manually parse your custom time string (maybe using regexes).

Comment: This answer currently assumes the date is also a local date, but I think the OP is saying that his date values are based on a UTC day.

Comment: @MattJohnson that isn't clear to me either. I intended *pure date* as *instance that holds only the date part*. Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: Inputs (B) will be created, e.g.: `new DateTime(2017, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)`

Comment: @Faust I intended it correctly then. The above code should work as per requirements.

Comment: Actually, no.  The `Kind` has no bearing on how `LocalDate.FromDateTime` is constructed.  To do this part correctly, you actually need to do something like `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(pureDate).InZone(zone).Date`.  As you have it now, it is treating the date as being based on the time zone, but the OP said it's based on UTC.  Would you like me to answer, or do you want to have another go at it? ;)

Comment: @MattJohnson From what I understand the OP is saying that even if the `DateTime` instance is created using `DateTimeKind.Utc` this doesn't matter because he will use it like a local date for the chosen time zone. Am I correct @Faust? More simply: is the desired output the same as in my answer?

Comment: From the comment thread in the question, I'm pretty sure he'st stating that the date is UTC-based, but the time is local time.  So they can't just combine, they have to normalize to one or the other.  And since you can't determine an offset from a local time without knowing the date, it must start by moving the date (at start of day) to the local time zone.

Comment: @MattJohnson Please note that I am aware that if the date should be effectively treated as UTC it must be converted to the desired time zone. It's just that I currently intend that this is not what the OP wants (but maybe I have mistaken his definition of *"4pm on May 23 as experienced in Los Angeles"*).

Comment: @MattJohnson Everything will be more clear if he adds the desired output inside his question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up working it out w/o NodaTime:

```
    public static DateTime Combine(DateTime date, string time, string timeZone)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimezoneDictionary[timeZone]);
        var timeOfDay = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "h:mm tt", null).TimeOfDay;
        var combined = date.Add(timeOfDay).Subtract(tzInfo.BaseUtcOffset);
        if (tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(combined))
            combined = combined.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        return combined;
    }
```

I also need this dictionary to convert IANA timezones to Microsoft:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, string> TimezoneDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "America/Los_Angeles", "Pacific Standard Time" },
        { "America/Denver", "Mountain Standard Time" },
        { "America/Chicago", "Central Standard Time" },
        { "America/New_York", "Eastern Standard Time" },
        //many more of course, just clipping this list for brevity.
    };
```